# Prediction Interval for log-tranformed data

Tags: regression, bayesian, confidence-interval

I am doing a linear regression on log-transformed data and I use the bayesian approach to model the predictive distribution and construct my 90% prediction Interval.
The problem with this approach is that my confidence interval are very large because of the exponential transformation. for an aleatoric standard deviation of 5% on my data set, the relative prediction interval width is of the order of 1.5 which is very large.
I think that the exponential transformation of the irreducible noise is making my confidence interval very large and not fitted to the data and I was wondering if there is any other approaches to attack this problem instead of the bayesian approach on the log-transformed data: [image]
Any solutions to obtain smaller prediction intervals ?

Comment: Why do you want a smaller prediction interval? Do your 90% PIs contain 99% of actual realizations in a holdout sample? If your data generating process is such that a log transform is justified, then wide PIs are simply what is needed. Alternatively: reduce the coverage your PIs aim for. A 50% PI will be narrower than a 90% one.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your answer. I totally agree with you on what you said. It's just that I am using real data and the log transformation is just a transformation. I was wondering if I am not losing some precision in the confidence interval by calculating it on the log transformed data and then back-transforming it.
I'll edit the question to make it more clear